# Change ImageButton Drawable automatically

Tags: android, random, android-imagebutton

I have 320 images in **drawable** directory  and ImageButton so when it's clicked, the Image have to be changed randomly, the image name is like this `file_xyz`, the **xyz** are numbers each one generated randomly using this code:

```
rand = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
x = rand.nextInt(3 - 0) + 0;
y = rand.nextInt(7 - 0) + 0;
z = rand.nextInt(9 - 0) + 0;
return "shape_" + x+ y+ z;
```

so this gives me a string which I want to use it to change the resource of ImageButton, so how to apply this and make the changes randomly in separate times?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
   int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(pDrawableName , "drawable", getPackageName());    
    imageview.setBackgroundResource(resID);
```

where `String pDrawableName = file_xyz` is your image name

Comment: I am trying this but when I write this code the `getResources()` don't show only `getClass()` @rafsanahmad007

Comment: use `getApplicationContext().getResources()`

Comment: the same with `getApplicationContext()` @rafsanahmad007

Comment: are u using it in fragment?

Comment: then try `getActivity().getResources()`...instead

Answer (score 1):

If you first create the exact filename string as in the drawable folder (I'll call it String image), you can do the following:

```
ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.image_button);
imageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.image);
```

Where image_button is whatever you have set as the ID for your image button.

Comment: Have you checked whether the image name generated exactly matches the image name in your drawable folder?